# Abandon an EU registered car outside of the EU

Tags: automobiles, eu, caucasus

This summer a friend and I are planning a one-way road trip from within the EU to the Caucasus region. Here we would like to leave the car behind and fly back home. Since we will be traveling on a budget our car will be an old banger. We therefore have no problem driving it to the nearest junk yard. But is this allowed? As we understand, the car gets a stamp in your passport as soon as you leave the EU.

Comment: “As we understand the car gets a stamp in your passport as soon as you leave the EU.” Not sure what you mean by that but I seriously doubt this is the case. I have left the EU by car many many times (to Switzerland) and never got anything.

Comment: @Relaxed, just like Norway and Iceland, Switzerland is part of the Schengen Area so free movement of goods.

Comment: It is in any case allowed to export a car from the EU. The main concern you will have is securing evidence of that to be able to stop insurance payments and avoid being held responsible for that car in the future. Another concern is what exactly is or is not allowed in each Caucasus country and how to import the car there (you cannot use a *carnet* or typical transit/temporary import procedures as these require proving you left the country with the vehicle).

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje Switzerland is part of the Schengen area but that has nothing at all to do with free movement of goods. It also has *ad hoc* agreements with the EU but I went to Switzerland by car many times before either of these so that does not explain anything. Still the border is “softer” than most and I could imagine things are a little different when going to Turkey for example. But I am still not sure how you suppose this stamp-of-the-passport thing would work. What's your understanding based on?

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje They are in Schengen, but not in the customs union! Goods have to be declared. The thing about a car is that when used for transportation no permanent import is assumed, thus no customs clearance. (I believe this is part of the Vienna convention on traffic, but would have to check where this is regulated)

Comment: There are AFAIK no EU wide regulations on this subject and I would assume that the details depend on exactly which EU country, in which the car is registered. There are no formalities required to take the car out of the EU, but there might be requirements to fulfil to get the car 'unregistered'. I once cancelled the registration of my car in Germany after having left the car in a non-EU country and I had to provide a declaration of the whereabouts of the car, but there was nothing more required.

Comment: Note also that the country where you leave the car will probably consider you to have _imported_ it and therefore may want you to pay import duty on it. You need to research _that country's_ particular customs rules.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, this is not the problem. For my country, Holland, it is basically enough to take the license plates with you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, this was where i was looking as well but importing a car is expensive and far more than the car is worth we are there for looking in demolishing it so we do not want to register it. But info on this is almost impossible to find. As of now we are looking into Georgia (country)

Comment: On entering Georgia, do you plan to clear the vehicle as a temporary import?

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje: That's what you need to research -- it would make sense for a country to consider an import if you bring the car into the country without bringing it out afterwards, no matter whether you register it for _driving_.

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje Is it really basically enough to take the license plates with you? I once exported and sold my car and my insurance (ABN-AMRO) demanded that I send a proof of the transaction. They did not care about the date the car was registered in another country or the date it was deregistered with the RDW and charged me for the whole time until I formally notified them with the proper paperwork.

Comment: I am really wondering where you get all your info and would urge you to double check these things with reliable sources or let us know where you got it from so we can check it. I am not trying to be difficult but I am afraid you are at risk of making some expensive mistake based on shaky info.

Comment: *Importing a car is expensive and far more than the car is worth*: Sounds about right but importing the car is really what you are doing so you need to be very careful. Even if you are comfortable with not doing things by the book, have you looked at the rules to drive into Georgia?  Will you use a carnet?

Comment: I've driven in and out of the EU several times (Slovenia, Croatia, and Bosnia, both before Slovenia joined the EU and after Croatia did), and there's no notation in anyone's passport about any vehicle.  Whatever administrative formalities you need to worry about, passport stamps are not among them.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is being confused by the fact that the entry and exit stamps given at road crossings of the Schengen external borders have a little picture of a car on them? This just indicates that the stamp was given at a _road_ border crossing, ***not*** "the traveler has a car with him". (Pedestrians and bicyclists get the same stamps!)

Comment: Instead of wrecking it, you might very well find a lot of people in that region that are willing to take it. If you want to become a local hero, give it to them for free!

Comment: @Sebastian, this would have been my first choice but is very hard as you have to import the care which is more than the actual value of the car

Comment: @HenningMakholm, no I'm not confusing I have crossed a couple of dozen borders but never with my own vehicle (thanks EU :D )
I'm aware of the different stamps for overland, over water and by air crossings. The stamp i'm referring too is the fact that they write on your visum for some countries that you took your own car with you:
https://www.wereldwijzer.nl/showthread.php?t=116413 (Dutch source)

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje You don't get a stamp as soon as you leave the EU but upon entering Turkey. It sounds like some form of temporary import paperwork, stamped directly in the passport for convenience and might be specific to Turkey. You have to look up the rules of the country you intend to leave the car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have completed the trip and can say that leaving a car behind without receiving money for it is easy as you donate the car to the foreign government. It however depends from country to country how easy this process is. My advice would be to consult you Embassy about this matter in the country you wish to leave a car.

Comment: What do you mean by “donate it to the foreign government"? Did you drive it to a police station or something? Just abandon it somewhere? What kind of paperwork, if any, did you need to enter the country? No deposit? How did you deal with your insurance and the authorities back home? What did the Dutch embassy in Georgia advise? Since you completed the trip, I think all these details would be very useful to dispel all the confusion in the question/comments?

Comment: @Relaxed, these kind of regulations change on a regular basis, since the trip has been over 3 years ago I would doubt if any of the information is still relevant. But the most important one is that you need to figure out how to get the car on a foreign license plate e.g. imported into the country. The formalities back home were dead simple, just go to the road administration and show the proof of import into another country. Out of cost savings I had already cancelled insurance and road taxes during the trip since we were out of coverage for the insurance..

Comment: @Relaxed, deposit is only required for countries via the carnet du passage system and Georgie is not on that list so it is just two stamps in your passport, one for the car and one for yourself upon crossing the border. The visa for the car is a stamp in your passport and had 90 days of validity. The Dutch embassy was of very little help as I guess with most embassies for these kind of holiday inquirers.

Comment: I do think this information is relevant and doesn't change that frequentely. To the extent that it does change, an answer stating that it's easy would seem misleading. Same thing for the embassy, if they were not helpful, why recommend contacting them? The insurance bit is worrisome, I doubt many people would be comfortable with that or find it easy, a big warning is in order!

Comment: Finally, I certaintely agree that importing the car is the main issue, several people explained that back when you asked the question and that's why I asked you about the paperwork entering Georgia. Clarifying this would hugely improve the answer. You can just edit that in directly, no need to discuss it in a long comment thread.

Answer (score 3):

Every country is happy with export. Just make sure that it is considered an export - you'll have to deregister your car in your home EU country so you don't have to pay insurance and road tax anymore.

But it mean you **import** your car to the country you're going to shrot it. It **might** be necessary to pay import taxes, which might exceed the actual worth of the car.

The scenario you might consider is to declare that your car got broken abroad and therefore it was trashed. You should inform yourself what procedures are required in that case. Depending on the laws of the country you come into it might be just the best option to crash you car against a tree a few meters from junkyard and get police protocol to proof in your registration country the car was damaged in an accident.

Comment: I'm pretty sure intentionally causing a crash would be illegal.

Comment: On the long run, lies have a habit of catching up with you. Simply state that "the car was no longer in a condition for the return trip" and get a receipt for the sale as trash.

Comment: The deregistering part is the easiest as my government allows for self demolition of the car so basically handing back paperwork and the license plates is enough.
I think we will just go and see what happens, in a worst case scenario we have to drive the car back to Greece..